# Creating an empty bitmap and drawing though canvas in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, drawing, android-canvas

I'd like to create an empty bitmap and set a canvas to that bitmap and then draw any shape on the bitmap.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

This is probably simpler than you're thinking:

```
int w = WIDTH_PX, h = HEIGHT_PX;

Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

// ready to draw on that bitmap through that canvas
```

Here's the official documentation on the topic: [Custom Drawing](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing)

Comment: If I create that within a seperate class, how would I reference the bitmap in another class. For example: Bitmap text = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), What to put here?); I need a textView within an opengl live wallpaper. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @bigstones I am following your code for creating bitmap in onSizeChanged() when I am creating bitmap I am getting OutOfMemoryError please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303759/outofmemoryerror-when-creatingbitmp

Comment: How can this be done in another thread while using SurfaceView?

Comment: just make sure x and y are not zero else it will throw exception illegal Argument

Comment: wow, this hasn't changed in 11 years?!

Answer (score -5):

Do not use Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888

Instead use
    int w = WIDTH_PX, h = HEIGHT_PX;

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444; // see other conf types
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

// ready to draw on that bitmap through that canvas
```

ARGB_8888 can land you in OutOfMemory issues when dealing with more bitmaps or large bitmaps.
Or better yet, try avoiding usage of ARGB option itself.

Comment: ARGB_4444 is deprecated now (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#ARGB_4444)