# How to draw alphabets(like ABC..)on bitmap images in android

Tags: android, canvas, draw

I'm developing android application to write ABC(letters)..on android bitmap images.and i want write letters on bitmap..any one can help me?

Comment: for FSM sake ... so you wana draw text on canvas ... canvas, draw text, canvas, drawtext, canvas, drawText ...

Comment: one example using canvas is here http://obviam.net/index.php/using-bitmap-fonts-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of [creating an empty bitmap and drawing though canvas in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663671/creating-an-empty-bitmap-and-drawing-though-canvas-in-android) . You need to do `Cancas c = new Canvas(bitmap);` and then draw onto the canvas using one of the the `drawText` methods.