# Android - Draw on a Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

Good morning. I'm writing an app to display and analyze GPR maps. Unfortunately the maps i've been given are txt files where char **0x00** represents black and **0xFF** represents white. The app it's at an early stage and I've managed to display those files on the screen using the following code:

```
public class DrawMap extends View {
    // ...
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        this.paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        this.paint.setStrokeWidth(1);

        for (int x = 0; x < this.map.getSize(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < this.map.getSize(); y++) {
                char val = this.map.getPixel(x, y);
                this.paint.setColor(Color.argb(0xff, val, val, val));
                canvas.drawPoint(10+x, 10+y, this.paint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since the size (width x height) of the map may vary, it would be easier to draw the map on a Bitmap, or something like that, first, and then display it to fit the size of the screen. I don't know how to achieve that. I need your help, please.

Comment: see all Canvas constructors

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int w = WIDTH_PX, h = HEIGHT_PX;

Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

// ready to draw on that bitmap through that canvas
```

source: [creating an empty bitmap and drawing though canvas in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663671/creating-an-empty-bitmap-and-drawing-though-canvas-in-android)

Hope that helps!